# convert RSA Publickey to base64 and vice versa

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I have a publicKey/privateKey pair generated from this function:

```
public static void generateKey() {
        try {
            final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            keyGen.initialize(2048);
            final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

            File privateKeyFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
            File publicKeyFile = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);

            // Create files to store public and private key
            if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
                privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            privateKeyFile.createNewFile();

            if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
                publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            publicKeyFile.createNewFile();

            // Saving the Public key in a file
            ObjectOutputStream publicKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile));
            publicKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPublic());
            publicKeyOS.close();

            // Saving the Private key in a file
            ObjectOutputStream privateKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile));
            privateKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPrivate());
            privateKeyOS.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Now I want to convert publicKey to `base64` while writing and use that base64 decode to get publicKey back ,how can that be done?

Comment: Hah, thought I was on Crypto due to the edit of e-sushi :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally if you want to store a file in base 64 you can simply encode the byte array. You can even put a Base64 stream in between the `ObjectOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream` (helpfully provided by the Base64 class within Java 8).

However, public keys and private keys have default encodings which can be accessed using their `getEncoded` methods:

```
PublicKey publicKey = key.getPublic();
byte[] encodedPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
String b64PublicKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPublicKey);

try (OutputStreamWriter publicKeyWriter =
        new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile),
                StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newEncoder())) {
    publicKeyWriter.write(b64PublicKey);
}
```

This saves the public key in `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` format, something that can be read and written by multiple types of software and cryptographic libraries.

For instance, you can [paste it in an online ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js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the online decoder will itself convert it to hex, but it will parse base 64 as well). The format of bytes are in so called ASN.1 / DER (which is a generic format, just like you can encode multiple types of files in XML).

---

If you want to have the key in OpenSSL compatible format (with a "PUBLIC KEY" header and footer) you can use a library such as Bouncy Castle (e.g. [`org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMWriter.html#JcaPEMWriter-java.io.Writer-)).

Comment: i got to know later abt getencoded method,this works great though i uses filewriter to write to file from base64 string ;)

Comment: I like to explicitly specify the character set. For base64 this is usually not an issue though, except when the default is UTF-16. Otherwise identical.

Comment: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPublicKey);` is all I needed...which would probably be obvious to someone more familiar with these file formats. Thanks!

Comment: @scottyseus Everything is obvious if you already know the answer :) The trick is to find a solution if you do *not* know the answer. Glad I could help you find it.